# Preventing Visual Studio to open files when searching

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I'm searching for some words in my project or solution, VS will keep opening every file where it found a coincidence, even though I didn't find what I was looking for in those files.

Is there a way to change this default behavior? It would be nice if instead of opening the file it'll show just a preview of it (the same as when you click on a file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use Find All instead.

It will present a list of all found matches in a "Find Results" pane, and you can click on the ones you want.

[image: Find All button]

[image: Find Results pane example]

Comment: That was not exactly what I was looking for, but I think is the closest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the behaviour by clicking inside the red circles!

[image]

Comment: Can you show a zoomed out screenshot?  It's hard to tell where you found these menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Change the search from "Entire Solution" to "Current Document" or something more precise. I'm not sure where this is located in VS2012, but in past versions it's a droplist in the "Find and Replace" tool (worded: "Look in:").

(Based on techie007's screenshot I'm guessing it might be in the dropdown from the toolbar??)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Edit -> Find and Replace -> Find in Files, keyboard shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+F with the option to search in the Entire Solution. It will list all occurences of the pattern in a results window where you can open files in the preview panel by selecting them in the results list.